# How to remove from an array using recursion in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

How to remove from an array using recursion in Java?

the array can be in any length and with any integers.

You may not use loops (while,for etc.)

for example

```
[2][4][2][0][9]
```

should print (2 4 0 9)

thanks for your assistance

Comment: What have you tried so far? (This looks like homework. If it is, please tag it as such.)

Comment: What element should be removed? A random one? You have to be more explicit.

Comment: What is to be removed? Duplicates? Please refine the question. Maybe you colud also state that it is a homework, if it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can't *remove* elements from an array in Java. Not with recursion, not with loops.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming here you don't actually want to *remove* the element [as @aioobe mentioned, it cannot be done], but you actually want to: "print all elements in the array, without duplicates". [I assume it from the example, you mention you want to print the specified output].

The way to do it is maintain a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) containing all elements you have already encountered, and print an element if and only if you encounter it and it is not in the set.

The recursion part will probably be: always handle the i element (`arr[i]`), and stop when 
`i == arr.length`. don't forget to increase i in each recursive call.

should look something like that:

```
public static void printNoDupes(int[] arr,int i,Set<Integer> seen) {
    if (i == arr.length) return;
    if (!seen.contains(arr[i])) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        seen.add(arr[i]);
    }
    printNoDupes(arr,i+1,seen);
}
public static void printNoDupes(int[] arr) { 
    printNoDupes(arr,0,new HashSet<Integer>());
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: If using `Set` is allowed, the all you need is `        System.out.println(new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2, 4, 2, 0, 9 })).toString());`

Comment: @MacroS: true, but the OP specifically asked for a recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array and then use recursion to remove element if it is same as the element previously found element / argument that indicates previous unique element.

And as others said, you can't remove elements from original array, you need to copy the elements that should be kept to a new array.

Comment: "...you need to copy the elements that should be kept to a new array"- but what dimension would this array have?

Comment: you can either initialize the new array's size same as the original one and use some special element to indicate its end or you can count the unique elements with the first call of the function then allocate a new array with that size, then store unique elements to new array in the second call.